# Setting the base URL for a Rails 4 app in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can set the Rails base URL in production using Passenger's `RailsBaseURI`. How do I do the same in development mode using the default Webrick server (`rails server`)?

I want to have a base URL like `http://localhost:3000/a_sub_dir/my_app_name` so that I can comprehensively test assets and routes just like in the production environment.

I tried

```
RailsStartModel::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "/a_sub_dir/my_app_name" do
  ...
  end
end
```

in `config/routes.rb`, but this only affects the routes, not the assets.